# How does webrtc manage to send UDP packets to a UWP client?

Tags: windows, uwp, webrtc, gstreamer, wireshark

I'm having great difficulty in getting gstreamer to send UDP packets to our UWP application (from a process on the same machine).  A previous version of the application is successfully using webrtc to do this.

As I understand from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh780593(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (search for "datagram") the UWP environment will block any incoming UDP traffic originating from a process on the same machine.  Yet using wireshark shows me that there is plenty of UDP traffic coming from our server when the client is displaying video originating from that server, such as:

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
3858    170.387279  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1021    62939 → 62943 Len=989
3859    170.392223  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1021    62939 → 62943 Len=989
3860    170.398190  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1021    62939 → 62943 Len=989
3861    170.407987  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 82  62943 → 62939 Len=50
3864    170.465804  10.90.15.232    10.90.15.232    STUN    128 Binding Request user: tM+9:f0ml
3865    170.465988  10.90.15.232    10.90.15.232    STUN    96  Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 10.90.15.232:62944
3872    170.478672  10.90.15.232    10.90.15.232    STUN    128 Binding Request user: f0ml:tM+9
3873    170.478784  10.90.15.232    10.90.15.232    STUN    96  Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 10.90.15.232:62940
3880    170.520962  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1032    62939 → 62943 Len=1000
3881    170.522957  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1032    62939 → 62943 Len=1000
3882    170.524946  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1032    62939 → 62943 Len=1000
3883    170.526933  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1032    62939 → 62943 Len=1000
3884    170.528002  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 74  62943 → 62939 Len=42
3885    170.530964  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1033    62939 → 62943 Len=1001
3886    170.531973  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1033    62939 → 62943 Len=1001
3887    170.533888  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1022    62939 → 62943 Len=990
3888    170.536886  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1022    62939 → 62943 Len=990
3889    170.543962  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 102 62943 → 62939 Len=70
3890    170.545020  172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 102 62939 → 62943 Len=70
```

Yet if I use this pipeline to generate video:

```
./gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,media=video,format=BGR,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host="172.28.176.1" port="5000"
```

I get nothing when it runs on the same machine that is running my client using this pipeline:

```
udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=RAW,sampling=BGR,width=(string)320,height=(string)240,clock-rate=90000,depth=(string)8 ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! queue ! d3d11videosink
```

The wireshark output in such a case is

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
522 38.046343   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
523 38.046632   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
524 38.046816   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
525 38.046972   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
526 38.047108   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
527 38.047239   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
528 38.047367   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1426    58998 → 5000 Len=1394
529 38.047510   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
530 38.047637   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
531 38.047763   172.28.176.1    172.28.176.1    UDP 1432    58998 → 5000 Len=1400
```

However, if the same gst-launch command is run from another machine on our network, I do get video in the client, which seems to confirm the statement in the MS doc above.

So, clearly the webrtc code is doing something to make it appear as if the traffic is coming from somewhere not on our machine.  It should be noted that the webrtc solution works even if our machine is not connected to a network, as long as we're running a virtual switch (using HyperV).

What sort of black magic is webrtc managing to pull off that we're not doing?